# Rigidbody character controller

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm working on a character controller, everything works fine except two things and I can't find a way to solve this :(
This is the code of my controller script :

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ControlsManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform playerBody;
    private Rigidbody _rigidbody;

    private Transform _playerCamera;

    private Vector2 _mousePosition;
    private Vector2 _precMousePosition;
    private float _rJoystickX;
    private float _rJoystickY;

    private float _sprint;
    private bool _jump;

    private Vector3 _bodyTranslation;
    private bool _bodyTranslationChange;
    private Vector3 _bodyRotation;
    private bool _bodyRotationChange;
    private Vector3 _cameraRotation;
    private bool _cameraRotationChange;


    private void Awake()
    {
        _rigidbody = playerBody.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        _playerCamera = Utilities.mainCamera.transform;
        _mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        _sprint = 1;

        // Cursor lock for camera rotation
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(Utilities.controls.lockCursorMouse))
        {
            if (Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.None)
            {
                Cursor.visible = false;
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            }
            else
            {
                Cursor.visible = true;
                Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            }
        }


        if (!Utilities.isGamePaused)
        {

            if (Input.GetJoystickNames().Length > 0 && Input.GetJoystickNames()[0] != "")
            {
                // Camera rotation for controller
                _rJoystickX = Input.GetAxis("RJoystickX");
                _rJoystickY = Input.GetAxis("RJoystickY");

                if (_rJoystickX != 0) {
                    _bodyRotation.y += Utilities.controls.controllerSens * _rJoystickX * Time.deltaTime;
                    _bodyRotationChange = true;
                }
                if (_rJoystickY != 0)
                {
                    _cameraRotation.x += Utilities.controls.controllerSens * _rJoystickY * Time.deltaTime;
                    _cameraRotationChange = true;
                }

                // Movements for controller
                if(Input.GetKey(Utilities.controls.sprintController))
                {
                    _sprint = 1.6f;
                }

                if (Input.GetAxis("LJoystickY") > 0)
                {
                    _bodyTranslation += playerBody.forward * _sprint * Time.deltaTime;
                    _bodyTranslationChange = true;
                }
                if (Input.GetAxis("LJoystickY") < 0)
                {
                    _bodyTranslation -= playerBody.forward * Time.deltaTime;
                    _bodyTranslationChange = true;
                }
                if (Input.GetAxis("LJoystickX") < 0)
                {
                    _bodyTranslation -= playerBody.right * Time.deltaTime;
                    _bodyTranslationChange = true;
                }
                if (Input.GetAxis("LJoystickX") > 0)
                {
                    _bodyTranslation += playerBody.right * Time.deltaTime;
                    _bodyTranslationChange = true;
                }
            }


            if (Cursor.lockState == CursorLockMode.Locked)
            {
                // Camera rotation for mouse
                _precMousePosition = _mousePosition;
                _mousePosition.x = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
                _mousePosition.y = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

                if (_mousePosition.x != _precMousePosition.x)
                {
                    _bodyRotation.y += _mousePosition.x * Utilities.controls.mouseSens;
                    _bodyRotationChange = true;
                }
                if (_mousePosition.y != _precMousePosition.y)
                {
                    _cameraRotation.x += -_mousePosition.y * Utilities.controls.mouseSens;
                    _cameraRotationChange = true;
                }

                // Movements for mouse

                _sprint = 1;
                if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
                {
                    _sprint = 1.6f;
                }

                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
                {
                    _jump = true;
                }

                if (Input.GetKey(Utilities.controls.forward))
                {
                    _bodyTranslation += playerBody.forward * (_sprint * Time.deltaTime);
                    _bodyTranslationChange = true;
                }
                if (Input.GetKey(Utilities.controls.backward))
                {
                    _bodyTranslation -= playerBody.forward * Time.deltaTime;
                    _bodyTranslationChange = true;
                }
                if (Input.GetKey(Utilities.controls.left))
                {
                    _bodyTranslation -= playerBody.right * Time.deltaTime;
                    _bodyTranslationChange = true;
                }
                if (Input.GetKey(Utilities.controls.right))
                {
                    _bodyTranslation += playerBody.right * Time.deltaTime;
                    _bodyTranslationChange = true;
                }

                ///////////////////////////////// Debug
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
                {
                    _bodyTranslation -= playerBody.up * Time.deltaTime;
                    _bodyTranslationChange = true;
                }
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
                {
                    _bodyTranslation += playerBody.up * Time.deltaTime;
                    _bodyTranslationChange = true;
                }

            }
        }

        // Rotations
        if (_bodyRotationChange)
        {
            playerBody.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(_bodyRotation);
        }
        _bodyRotationChange = false;
        _bodyRotation = Vector3.zero;
        if (_cameraRotationChange)
        {
            _playerCamera.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(_cameraRotation);
        }
        _cameraRotationChange = false;
        _cameraRotation = Vector3.zero;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            Application.Quit();
        }

    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

        if (_bodyTranslationChange)
        {
            _rigidbody.AddForce(_bodyTranslation * Utilities.controls.playerSpeed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        }

        if (_jump)
        {
            _jump = false;
            _rigidbody.AddForce(playerBody.up * 500, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }

        _rigidbody.drag = playerBody.position.y > -0.6f ? 1 : 8;

        _bodyTranslationChange = false;
        _bodyTranslation = Vector3.zero;
    }    
}
```

The main two problems are :

1. As I do rotations in Update, and movements in FixedUpdates, there is some annoying jitter when I both move and rotate at the same time. I tried to show this in a gif but everything seems laggy so I can't really show it.
2. As I use AddForce() to move my character, I had to increase the drag of my rigidbody (up to 8) si it doesn't "slide" when you stop moving. This works great but now I can't jump properly because of that. I found a workaround, by putting the drag back to 1 when I'm in the air, but then if I jump and move, I move 8x faster in the air which is annoying aswell.

Am I doing thinks completely wrong ? I first did not use AddForce but normal vector translations to move the character, but collisions were buggy as hell, I could go through most walls, objects... etc

Thanks if you read all that !

Comment: do you have animations that are adding to this "jitter"?

Comment: Not, for the moment nothing else than that

Answer (score -1):

when working with Pyhsics (RB) NEVER change the transform directly and never ever to this in Update! all changes have to be made inside FixedUpdate!

playerBody.localRotation *= Quaternion.Euler(_bodyRotation); <-- in Update.

Also use Rigidbody.MoveRotation instead of directy change values.
This happens because of pyhsics will work in a different update process and when you change Values within this process unity gets confused and you break the physics -> Jitter

Comment: And if I move rotation in FixedUpdate aswell (what I was doing before), it's still jittery because FixedUpdate is called less than Update

Comment: but in Fixedupdate u just tell the physics where he should go and he interpolates the frames that are running in your Update. Again do NOT set Position/rotation directly to an RigidBody! use Functions like "Rigidbody.MoveRotation"

Comment: I'll try with MoveRotation in FixedUpdate, but again as it is call less than Update (if you have decent fps) there will be frames where FixedUpdate was not called and it will jitter

Comment: Yep, it's exactly the same, maybe even more jittery
Using : camera rotation (x axis) in Update / body rotation (y axis) and translation in FixedUpdate

Comment: the camera update / position rotation has also to be done in fixed Update ;) otherwise u have always position missmatches/Jitter ;)

Comment: _**Bad advice**_. It's absolutelly _false_ that you _"have"_ to do physics in `FixedUpdate` or that you should _"NEVER"_ do physics stuff in `Update`. It's just that physical changes will _not be applied_ until the next physics pass/tick (right after `FixedUpdate`), and so there is no point having to handle `DeltaTime` and other such stuff when you have a callback that is already synchronous to run just before the physics engine's passes/ticks. - Also, Unity is not _"confused"_. _**You're "telling" it to do two different things**_ through two different systems (`Transform` and `Rigidbody`).

Comment: when you change transform within update while running physics (RG) on this Object you break the pysics calculations for shure... look at Unity Doc....

Comment: @Vampirasu - And _why_ does that _"breaks the physics calculations"_, exactly? Excuse my sarcasm, but... Might it _**possibly**_ be because your `Rigidbody` is telling the physics engine to change the `Transform` in one way, while _you_ are telling the object's `Transform` to do a _different_ thing? _Exactly as I explained?_ --- The physics is not _broken_, it's working _exactly as it should_. It's not it's fault that _**you**_, as the developer, has created a situation where you're giving it, directly or indirectly, two different sets of conflicting inputs. That's my point. 

Answer (score -1):

Ok, after hours of trying to make something smooth with Rigidbody, I can't get anything perfect.

I'll just use a basic Character controller and handle collisions myself.

Thanks anyway !

Comment: This answers nothing. This is not a site dedicated to solving your problem. Rather it's a site dedicated to seeking and sharing knowledge through a Q&A format. Answers are not meant to be about an ambiguous mention _that_ you solved your problem or given up midway. Answers should be about _how_ you solved your problem, such that future readers with similar issues can _learn_ from you.